# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'null, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: asp.net

Owin signalr not work when add coors in webConfig.

i made an api

```
        public ActionResult GetById(string Id)
        {
            Response<dynamic> result2 = new Response<dynamic>();

            var result = SolicitudServicioBl.GetById(Guid.Parse(Id));
            var x = result.Data;
            result2.Result = result.Result;
            result2.Message = result.Message;
            if (result.Result == Models.DTO.Response.Reply.success)
            {
                result2.Data = new
                {
                    Id = x.Id.ToString(),
                    x.Estatus,
                };
            }

            return Json(result2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

After add to the webconfig

```
 <customHeaders>  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> 
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, *" /> 
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
```

And all was working well, After i added owin signalr, i add a StartUp class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            //app.MapSignalR();
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {

                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {

                };

                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);

            });

        }
    }
```

The problem here is ,signalr doesnt work:
  The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'null, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.